# How can I create Android images with good resolution?

Tags: android, layout, screen, resolution

I'm creating an Android application. The main activity layout will have a background image that will wrap with the whole screen. What resolution should I use to create the background image? What about DPI? I need it to be compatible with all devices
(for example the HTC Sensation screen's resolution is 540 × 960 pixels).

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you is to start reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article, it contains the best practices for supporting multiple screen sizes and densities.

**EDIT:**

I use the following directories to store the drawables for maximum size and density optimization:

**Small screens support**

- drawable-small-hdpi
- drawable-small-ldpi

**Normal screen support**

- drawable-normal-mdpi
- drawable-normal-hdpi

**Large screens support**

- drawable-large-mdpi

**Tablet screen support**

- drawable-xlarge-mdpi

Of course not every time this solution is the best, aqs's solution is more common used. You can follow [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html) site to track which screen sizes and density's are most used and decide which of the screens worth support for your application. And of course you can read about the [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to understand better what are your options.

Comment: yea, and just to answer to the point, create 3 different images for the most commonly used used pixel densities:ldpi, mdpi,hdpi. ldpi with lowest resolution, and hdpi with the maximum resolution

Comment: thank you for your answer , in the documentation : "for a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi)" when i create an image with 480x800 in photoshop, it's very large than my HTC screen , should i use this size even it seems large ? other question , what resolution should i use , 72 like for web images ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can use that screen size but I don't know what to say about the resolution.. maybe you should use the same values as for the web images as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You should read Supporting multiple screens. You must define dpi on your emulator. 240 is hdpi, 160 is mdpi and below that are usually ldpi.

Extract from Android Developer Guide link above:

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).  
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).  
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).  
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO answer of @Cata is a bit misleading because of mixing screen size and screen density for providing graphics.

I think the best practice is to distinguish this two things by providing:

- `different size images (PNGs) for different densities` and
- `different layouts for different generalized screen sizes`.

By doing so developer can reduce number of different images to 4 categories (`ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi`) if he wants to support all currently existing densities. Of course XML layouts files for different (`small, normal, large, xlarge`) screen sizes are necessary if we support them but it is much easier to make/edit/correct/adjust xml files than PNGs.

A bit more details and explanation u can find in [my previous answer about this topic on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761278/304270).

Hope u find this answer useful. Cheers.